# Use any Activity Indicator library with Moya

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I am using [Moya Networking](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) in my iOS project. I made a class which has below method:

```
class UserAdapter{

    static func getUsers(amount:Int=2, gender:Gender = .Male, success successCallback: @escaping ([UserModelMain]) -> Void, error errorCallback: @escaping (Swift.Error) -> Void, failure failureCallback: @escaping (MoyaError) -> Void) {

        let endpointClosure = { (target: UserTarget) -> Endpoint<UserTarget> in
            let defaultEndpoint = MoyaProvider.defaultEndpointMapping(for: target)
            return defaultEndpoint.adding(newHTTPHeaderFields: ["": ""])
        }

        let provider = MoyaProvider<UserTarget>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure, plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true), NetworkActivityPlugin(networkActivityClosure: { (activity, target) in
            switch activity
            {
            case .began:
                print("Network Activity began")
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            case .ended:
                print("Network Activity ended")
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            }
        })])

        provider.request(.getUsers(amount: amount, gender: gender)) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                 //TODO

            }
        }
    } }
```

I am calling this from my view controller:

```
UserAdapter.getUsers(amount: 8, gender: .Female, success: { (response) in

    }, error: { (error) in
        // show error from server
    }, failure: { (error) in
        // show Moya error
    })
```

Instead of `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` I need to use any custom loading library like, [NVActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView). How to do this?

Comment: Do you want it to be able to work with any custom library or do you want it to work specifically with ` NVActivityIndicatorView`? Also, it would be better to reuse `MoyaProvider` and declare it outside the function.

Comment: Any loader library

Comment: Thankyou , i declared it outside the function as "static let provider "

Comment: I want to use any loader library with it, I don't want view controller to handle my loader start/stop but this UserAdapter class to do the job. The issue is that loader view is obviously in scene/view controller. How to handle that in UserAdapter class via delegate closure or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static func getUsers(amount:Int=2, 
gender:Gender = .Male, 
success successCallback: @escaping ([UserModelMain]) -> Void, 
error errorCallback: @escaping (Swift.Error) -> Void, 
failure failureCallback: @escaping (Moya.MoyaError) -> Void, 
progress progressCallback: ProgressBlock?, 
activity networkActivityCallback: @escaping (_ change: NetworkActivityChangeType) -> Void) {

            let userProvider = MoyaProvider<UserTarget>(endpointClosure: { (target: UserTarget) -> Endpoint<UserTarget> in
                let defaultEndpoint = MoyaProvider.defaultEndpointMapping(for: target)
                return defaultEndpoint.adding(newHTTPHeaderFields: ["": ""])
            }, plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true), NetworkActivityPlugin(networkActivityClosure: { (activity, target) in
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = (activity == .began)
                networkActivityCallback(activity)
                switch activity
                {
                case .began:
                    print("Network Activity began")
                case .ended:
                    print("Network Activity ended")
                }
            })])
    //Other statements

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
print("Network Activity began")
Helper.showHUD()
UserAdapter.getUsers(amount: 8, gender: .Female, success: { (response) in
    print("Network Activity ended")
    Helper.hideHUD()
}, error: { (error) in
    // show error from server
    print("Network Activity ended")
    Helper.hideHUD()
}, failure: { (error) in
    // show Moya error
    print("Network Activity ended")
    Helper.hideHUD()
})
```

Comment: Thankyou, but my question is that how to add this to UserAdapter class. I dont want viewController to handle loader.

Comment: I want to use any loader library with it, I don't want view controller to handle my loader start/stop but this UserAdapter class to do the job. The issue is that loader view is obviously in scene/view controller. How to handle that in UserAdapter class via delegate closure or something?

Answer (score 0):

## Copy Paste from Working Project

I have faced this issue and here is the solution.

#### Network Manager

```
class HomeNetworkManager: HomeNetworkable
{
   // MARK: Properties

   private let provider: MoyaProvider<HomeAPI>

   // MARK: Initiallization

   init(provider: MoyaProvider<HomeAPI>)
   {
      self.provider = provider
   }

   convenience init()
   {
      let networkActivityClosure: NetworkActivityPlugin.NetworkActivityClosure = { (activity, _) in
      switch activity
      {
          case .began:
              Activity.startAnimating()
          case .ended:
              Activity.stopAnimating()
          }
      }
        
      var plugins : [PluginType] = []

      let networkActivityPlugin = NetworkActivityPlugin(networkActivityClosure: networkActivityClosure)
      plugins.append(networkActivityPlugin)
    
      let networkLogger = NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)
      plugins.append(networkLogger)
    
      let provider = MoyaProvider<HomeAPI>(plugins: plugins)
      self.init(provider: provider)
   }

   // MARK: Methods - Methods defined in HomeNetworkable Protocol
}
```

Then easily use it and get activity indicator works for free:

```
let homeNetworkManager = HomeNetworkManager()
```

> **Note :** `Activity` is a class with static methods shows my custom activity indicator.

Good luck!